# An error has occurred in the JavaScript Console. Functionality might be affected

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer

HI I am getting this peculiar information in my console of IE 11 ,

> An error has occurred in the JavaScript Console. Functionality might
>   be affected.

this information is showed when I run a for loop to form the list of elements in ul tag for 4000 times,
I put the i in console but it stops at 999 and this message is shown below.

```
      for (var i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
                console.log(i)
                param_html="'"+element_list[i]["sElement"]["#text"].replace('/', '')
+ "','" + element_list[i]["sElementDesc"]["#text"].replace('/', '')+"'";
                html += "<li class='ui-widget-content  addElementandlocation image-" + element_list[i]["iInciLocFlag"]["#text"].replace('/', '') + " onclick=dao.load_location_element_loca(" + param_html + "); module='location2'    id='" + element_list[i]["sElement"]["#text"] + "'><span   class=code>" + element_list[i]["sElement"]["#text"] + "</span><span  class=description>" + element_list[i]["sElementDesc"]["#text"].replace('/', '') + "</span></li>";

            }
```

I dont know why its not running more than 999.
Thank you.

Comment: Im having the same issue at the moment. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this same error recently, while testing some JavaScript code in IE 11.

The solution for me was to reduce the number of times that the console.log prints from within my FOR loop.

For example, printing to the console only if the index is divisible by 20.

```
for (var i = 0, j = 4000; i < j; i++) {
  if (i % 20 == 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

(Link to jsFiddle page can also be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cybermention/m9vx6bvt/).)

Answer (score 0):

Does element_list contain more than 999 values? Check the length of element_list

Comment: yeah it has more than 999 actually it has 4197

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = items.map(function(item) {
return item['name'];
});
```

I was getting the same error but managed to bypass it by using the .map function.

http://api.jquery.com/map/