# javascript nested for loops not iterating all the way through

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, nested-loops

I was attempting to place a `circle` on an HTML canvas that measured `1920 * 850` on `(x, y)` where `x` varied by `50` and `y` varied by `75`.  I set up a nested `for` loop to accomplish this but soon found it was not working, i.e. the loop stopped after a certain point.  I then did some scenarios with simple nested for loops without the `circle` placement code and found that they were also stopping after a certain point.

In the code below, I have a simple nested `for` loop and upon running it, it stops when `i = 14` and `j = 19`.  In the `console`, it just states 'An error has occurred in the Javascript console

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  j = 0
  for (var j = 0; j < 70; j++) {
    console.log('i: ' + i + ' j: ' + j);
  }
}
```

Is there something fundamentally wrong here, this seems like such a simple piece of code but I do not know why it would stop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Working fine for me. What is the error exactly?

Comment: Why do `j = 0` twice?

Comment: seems like You've not put whole code, cuz Your with `console.log` works ok

Comment: _"it stops when i = 14 and j = 19. In the console it just states 'An error has occurred in the Javascript console"_ Cannot reproduce. Can you create a stacksnippets to reproduce? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Frank, I read in some other posts that the inner loop needed to be re-initialized so that is why I added it, it did not make much sense but I am new to javascript so I thought perhaps for loops worked a little differently that in other languages such as vb.net or c#. That was the whole code snippet.

Comment: It is being reinitialized when you do `var j = 0`

Comment: _"That was the whole code snippet."_ Then _"it stops when i = 14 and j = 19. In the console it just states 'An error has occurred in the Javascript console"_ is not accurate or reproducible?

Comment: Declare `j = 0` at top of your code, along with other declarations.

Comment: So I have Windows 7 pro and was using IE 11 to do the testing and I am still getting the issue, however, when I run it in Chrome it works just fine.  Chrome version is : 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Just curious if anyone has been able to recreate this issue in IE 11?

Comment: IE11.. ha. srsly?

Comment: vol7ron, not sure what you mean, please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue, sort of. I found a post where the console log was not showing the output of a for loop after 999. Additionally, there was an error in my initial javascript loop to produce the circles, I did not use a beginPath after each circle was drawn and that was giving very messed up results.

[I.E. Console log with for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065351/an-error-has-occurred-in-the-javascript-console-functionality-might-be-affected)

After reviewing this I realized my code might still be running but the console is not showing it.  So I rewrote the code to fill the canvas as I had started out to and it is working now.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var header = $('#header');
    var footer = $('#footer');

    var canvas = $('#myCanvas3')[0];
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight - header.height() - footer.height();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;

    for (var y = 1; y < 18; y++)
        {
            i = y * 50;
            for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++)
            {
                j += 1;
                if (j == 50) {
                    console.log('x: ' + x);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
                    ctx.arc(x, i, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                    ctx.fill();
                    j = 0;
                }
            }
        }

});
```

Lesson learned - when drawing items on the canvas make sure to use a beginPath when drawing a new item!!